# Using field from domain class in constrinsts

Tags: grails, grails-orm

How can I set max value for GORM using one field from domain class?

```
class Test {
    Date start
    Date end

    static constraints = {
        end max: new Date()
        start max: end // <-- here is the problem
    }
}
```

If I'm doing like above I'm getting error:

```
No such property: start for class: org.grails.datastore.mapping.config.groovy.MappingConfigurationBuilder
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: start for class: org.grails.datastore.mapping.config.groovy.MappingConfigurationBuilder
...
```

I'm using **Grails 3.0.4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the requirement is to set the max value of `start` to be the `end` date in the runtime. This can only be achieved by using a custom validator as below:

```
class Test {
    Date start
    Date end

    static constraints = {
        end max: new Date()
        start validator: { val, obj ->
            // val - The value of the property on which the validator is applied
            // obj - this object
            if( val > obj.end ) {
                // return false
                // or return max error
                // or return ['some message to pick up from message bundle']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Refer [validator](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) for additional details.